# can't update chromium issue

Tags: command-line, update-manager, chromium

I am working ok kiosk application where OS installed is Ubuntu 16.4 
and it has chromium browser.
This browser run in kiosk, when it start it gives me warning message box of "can't Update chromium".
I cant do any changes in chromium using frontend as we have no input keyboard of touch screen.
I want to hide that popup message as it blocks the view of page running ok chromium
can anyone guide me this how and what backend command will stop showing that popup.

Answer (score 3):

From what I've gathered on the web, Chromium checks frequently (every 2 hours or so) its own build time against current time. Older then 12 weeks? Show popup. The reason is security - running an outdated browser increases your risk.

The best (and the only *correct*) way to solve this is running an up-to-date chromium build. However, you may run a raspberry pi (raspbian buster at the time of writing) and the repos do *not* have an update.

I'm running a kiosk mode chromium, no mouse, no keyboard, and its displaying my own webpage. In this situation, I can accept the risk of an outdated browser and... try to suppress the message. Different suggestions didn't work (e.g. `--disable-component-update` does not), more info:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=264399

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=943668

Right now I'm trying

```
chromium-browser --disable-infobars --check-for-update-interval=1209600 --simulate-outdated-no-au='Tue, 31 Dec 2099 23:59:59 GMT' --kiosk 'http://localhost:5000/'
```

The update check interval is two weeks and my raspi runs updates+reboot once a week. Not sure if the simulate oudated hack works, I just combined all of the solutions now :-S